# Perform element wise multiplication of vectors efficiently?

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I have to perform matrix updating by `M = M + c*a*a'` large number of times, where `c` is a constant and **a** is a column vector. If the size of matrix is larger than 1000, this simple updating will cost most of the time of my function, typically more than 1 min counted by `profile`.

Main codes are:

```
for i = 1:N
    _do something..._
    for k = 1:n
        a(1:k) = M(1:k,1:k)*p(1:k);
        M(1:k,1:k) = M(1:k,1:k)+c*a(1:k)*a(1:k)';
        M(1:k, k+1) = b(1:k);
        M(k+1, 1:k) = b(1:k)';
        M(k+1, k+1) = x;
        ......
    end
end
```

I have preallocated all variables, column vectors **p** and **b** are known, and `x` is another constant.

As I have large number of data to process by this function, does there exist more efficient alternative to this matrix updating?

Comment: please post your original, but simplified (!) code.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thanks, have edited my question.

Comment: It feels like an [**XY-problem**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you should rethink your question. As it is, the loop seems your best option.

Comment: @thewaywewalk What I want is to perform least squares in the loop `k=1:n`. This means that the coefficient matrix **A** in iteration _k_ is the coefficient matrix in previous iteration _k-1_ with an additional column. So to avoid computing `pinv(A)` in each iteration, I just update the `inv(A'*A)` from `k=2` by codes pasted in question. This works well for small `n`. I think the extending of space for element wise multiplication `a(1:k)*a(1:k)'` is the main reason that slows the computation, so I wonder whether there exist a better way to avoid this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate `a` vectors  to create  a matrix `A` then apply multiplication just one time.

```
A =[a1 a2 a3];
M = c * A * A.';
```

consider the example

```
A = rand(5,5);
M = 0;
c=4;
for n = 1:5
    M = M + c * A(:,n) * A(:,n).';
end
```

and this one

```
M1 = c * A * A.'
```

both `M` and `M1` are equal

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault that I did no make my question clear. In fact, vector **a** is derived from matrix M of previous iteration. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using bsxfun?

In any case, bsxfun is **much** faster than regular multiplication, but the vectors/matrices have to be of equal length (which they are for you, aren't they?), and it's operating elementwise (i.e. a Nx1 vector bsx-multiplied with itself yields a Nx1 vector, multiplied with the transpose however yields a NxN matrix).

see https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html

use as
    bsxfun(@times, a, a')

Comment: ok, pity
I would have added this as a comment had I the privilege to do so, yet (and as you see, first comment, first mistake ^^)